# Can't ping computer when its screen is locked

Tags: windows-7, networking

When my Windows 7 desktop locks its screen due to inactivity, I am unable to connect to it remotely. After I discovered this, I tried pinging the machine, which failed.

However, as soon as I walk over to the computer and unlock the screen, I am able to both ping it and remote in again.

Why does the computer appear dead to the network as soon as the screen locks?

Comment: Test this: If you locked it manually would the same thing occur? add info :What is the type of connection?

Comment: Is the system asleep?

Comment: Windows is turning off your network adapter when it locks. Go into your network adapter configuration and uncheck `Let the computer turn off this device to save power.`

Comment: @resmon6 I'd post that as an answer.  Sounds fairly likely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows is turning off your network adapter when it locks. Go into your network adapter configuration and uncheck `Let the computer turn off this device to save power`.

Comment: Can't test this right now, although I have changed the setting, but marked it down as the answer because I feel it's extremely likely.

I know it is unrelated to the Firewall as we have a few PCs in the office that aren't having this problem.

Comment: Confirmed as answer! Mucho gracias!

Comment: I'm happy to help

Answer (score 1):

This is Not Normal Windows/system behaviour.

I strongly feel its your firewall, that is "blocking incoming packets" the moment your system is "Locked"

To test on this, disable your firewall for a short while.. Lock your desktop and see if you are able to remote connect/ping

If you are able to, then there's probably some setting within your firewall software that you need to look for that is blocking incoming connections/packets when your desktop is locked..